# How to add recommended products in django oscar dashboard

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am using django-oscar == 1.6.1 for a project.
I am trying to add recommended products to an individual product in the dashboard, currently I see that the recommended product field is empty, how do I populate it and give the ranking?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a streaming search field, whatever you type should search for related term in your existing products database.

For example, if you type `<search_term>` it would ultimately query (after several intermediate queries of substrings) & hit `http://localhost:8000/dashboard/catalogue/product-lookup/?q=<search_term>`, the view for which can be [found here](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.6.1/src/oscar/apps/dashboard/catalogue/views.py#L630). As you can see, it searches the product titles only, if you need something else, you can always [modify it](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/customisation.html#customising-oscar).

By the looks of it, you haven't populated your products database yet, or there's something else wrong with your installation or setup.

Comment: Well, I do have a lot of products in my database, 14 in total. I guess I have to check my settings file?

Comment: You can fire up the shell and see if you can run the query `Products.browsable.all()` and get results, that'll tell you if you've setup the products correctly.

Comment: I am getting the ProductQueryset, but there is one weird thing, on the /dashboard/ it shows 14 products, while I just have 12 products in /dashboard/catalogue/.

Comment: I suggest you update the question with the new info (including how you uploaded the products, the gist if manual upload else the migration & data file).